# Hazelcast: Unable to get alive cluster connection

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-cloud

I have one spring-boot microservice connects to hazelcast using hazelcast, hazelcast-client and hazelcast-spring 3.6 version. I was able to connect on java 8 but as soon as migrated to java 17 with no other code change started getting error:  thread="hz.client_0_obj-cartmap.cluster-listener" category="com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientClusterService"  Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 8128 ms later, attempt 1 of 1000. Cluser seems good, getting response on http://obj1.cartmp.intqa102.syseng.tmcs:5701/hazelcast/rest/cluster

````
  
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CartMappingHazelcastConfig.class);
  
  @Value("${cart.mapping.cache.local.instanceName}")
  private String localInstanceName;
  
  @Value("${cart.mapping.cache.common.groupName}")
  private String groupName;
  
  @Autowired
  HazelcastConfigProperties hazelcastConfigProperties;
  
  @Bean
  public CartIdBuilderFactory cartIdBuilderFactory() {
      return new CartIdBuilderFactory(this.localInstanceName);
  }
  
  @Bean
  public Serializer cartMappingSerializer() {
      return new CartMappingKryoSerializer();
  }
  
  @Bean
  public Map<String, ClientConfig> hazelCastClientConfigs() {
    Map<String, ClientConfig> clientConfigsMap = new HashMap<>();
  
    hazelcastConfigProperties.getConfigs().stream()
      .forEach(cacheProperties -> {
        clientConfigsMap.put(cacheProperties.getName(), makeClientConfig(cacheProperties));
      });
  
    return clientConfigsMap;
  }
  
  @Bean
  public Map<String, HazelcastInstance> hazelCastInstances() {
      return this.hazelCastClientConfigs().keySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k, k -> HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(hazelCastClientConfigs().get(k))));
  
  }
  
  @Bean
  public Map<String, CacheManager> registeredCacheManagers() {
      return this.hazelCastInstances().keySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(k->k, k -> new HazelcastCacheManager(this.hazelCastInstances().get(k))));
  
  }
  
  @Bean
  public CartMappingCacheManager cartMappingCacheManager() {
      return new HazelcastCartCacheManager(this.registeredCacheManagers(), this.localInstanceName, CartContentsProvider.COMMERCE_API_PROVIDER_ID, cartIdBuilderFactory());
  }
  
  private ClientConfig makeClientConfig(CacheConfigProperty cacheConfigProperty) {
      ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
  
      config.getGroupConfig().setName("obj-cartmap").setPassword(cacheConfigProperty.getPassword());
      config.getNetworkConfig()
              .setConnectionAttemptLimit(1000)
              .setSmartRouting(true)
              .setRedoOperation(true)
              .setConnectionTimeout(5000)
              .setConnectionAttemptPeriod(10000);
  
      config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("obj1.cartmp.intqa102.syseng.tmcs");
  
      config.getSerializationConfig()
        .addSerializerConfig(new SerializerConfig()
                               .setTypeClass(CartMapping.class)
                               .setImplementation(cartMappingSerializer()));
  
      return config;
  }```

Any suggestion?
````